# Hide a column in Grafana panel

Tags: regex, grafana

I have a query:

```
Select * from my table
```

That gives me 20 fields.

There is 3 columns that all begin with `index` in column name that I want to hide.

I could explicit all fields in query, but for 17 fields, it might not be the best solution.

In `Options`,

I use this regex, `/index(.*)/`

When I change the column header, I can see the header of the 3 columns is changing which means my regex is OK.

But when I change the type from `String` to `Hidden`, all my column except time disappear.

Is there something I am missing ?

Comment: What is your Grafana version?

Comment: Right now, I am in v7.beta3, but I had the same issue with the latest v6